# Python Libraries can't be detected

Tags: python, import, libraries

I installed some python libraries, but they can't be detected. In pycharm they are orange so excluted and Visual Studio Code says "Import "cv2" could not be resolved" if I want to include open cv. I also had 3 Versions of Python at first, but now I only have one left is that a problem?

Deleted old Versions of Python and Anaconda was the only thing that made the pip comand work again.
I looked up if everything is installed with "pip list".

Comment: 404 code not found?

Comment: I'm guessing that `pip` in your command line is not talking to the same python as your interpreter in VSCode. Try `python -m pip -V` and see if that interpreter is the same one you have selected

Comment: It still says "No module named cv2" what is the librarie that I want

Comment: I wouldn't bother if `IDE` can't detect module (they also may have some bugs) because it has nothing to do with running code. I would bother if it can't run this code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have the installed python in your path. The first interpreter it reaches in path will be used, if not just add it to your path

```
where.exe python
C:\dist\venvs\trk-fullstack-test\Scripts\python.exe
C:\dist\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\mobj\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

$ENV:PATH = "C:\dist\Python310;$ENV:PATH"

where.exe python
C:\dist\Python310\python.exe
C:\dist\venvs\trk-fullstack-test\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\mobj\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

All modules installed with pip will follow the python interpreter used.

Recommend taking a look a `https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html`
to see how virtual environments are handled.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not the version of Python. When you install Python you can choose advanced options and enable library installing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).